# My SQL query runs perfectly, but when I add the CTE function, I get an error

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

My SQL query runs perfectly, but when I add the CTE function, I get an error
Please check this code and let me know what's wrong with the CTE:

```
WITH Consumption_details(UnitId, consumption, monthof, yearof) AS
(
    SELECT 
        UnitId, SUM(consumption) AS consumption, 
        monthof, yearof  
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             UnitId, apartment_consumption, 
             DATEPART(MONTH, day) AS monthof, 
             DATEPART(YEAR,day) AS yearof 
         FROM 
             MeterReading) AS t
    GROUP BY 
        yearof, monthof, UnitId
    HAVING 
        monthof = 2 AND yearof = 2022
    ORDER BY
        UnitID
)
```

Comment: For future reference, post the error message you encounter - all of it. "Gives me error" is never a useful thing to write by itself.

Comment: Also, since `monthof` and `yearof` aren't aggregated with a `SUM` or `COUNT` or similar, you should *NOT* use `HAVING`- but just a regular `WHERE` - for those conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `ORDER BY` inside the CTE (unless you also include `TOP`, which you shouldn't do in this case), and you need to *do something* with the CTE - it's just an expression, not a query on its own.

```
;;;/*be safe!*/;;;With cd(SonnenUnitId, consumption, monthof, yearof) AS
    (
        SELECT SonnenUnitId, ...
        ...
        GROUP BY yearof, monthof, SonnenUnitId
        HAVING monthof =2 and yearof =2022
    )
SELECT * FROM cd Order by SonnenUnitID;
```

As an aside, this query could be a *whole* lot more efficient with no need for a CTE *and* a subquery, any of the HAVING, and the scan potentially becoming a seek.

```
DECLARE @mo int = 2, @yo int = 2022;


DECLARE @m date = DATEFROMPARTS(@yo, @mo, 1);

SELECT SonnenUnitId, 
  SUM(apartment_consumption) AS consumption, 
  monthof = @mo, 
  yearof = @yo  
FROM dbo.SonnenMeterReading
  WHERE [day] >= @m 
    AND [day] < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @m)
  GROUP BY SonnenUnitId
  ORDER BY SonnenUnitId;
```

Comment: Did you put all those semi-colons there just to wind @larnu up?

Comment: @DaleK hahaha no.